# How can I delete the same row in multiple sheets without repeating code?

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sheets("CDGL Data").Select
Rows([1]).EntireRow.Delete

Sheets("CDGL Data (2)").Select
Rows([1]).EntireRow.Delete

Sheets("CDGL Data (3)").Select
Rows([1]).EntireRow.Delete

Sheets("CDGL Data (4)").Select
Rows([1]).EntireRow.Delete
```

Comment: All the worksheets in a workbook are being considered or some selected sheets of a particular workbook.

Comment: Its only those 4 worksheets that I need selected but there are others that should not be referenced

Answer (score 2):

Regroup them into an `Array`:

```
Sheets(Array("CDGL Data", "CDGL Data (2)", "CDGL Data (3)", "CDGL Data (4)")).Select
Rows("1:1").Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

(based on macro-recorder code, great for discovering the Excel object model and API)

Answer (score 1):

You will want to iterate through the worksheets and delete the row:

```
Sub delrow()
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Left(ws.Name, 9) = "CDGL Data" Then
        Rows(1).Delete
    End If
Next ws
End Sub
```

This will delete the row from every sheet that has `CDGL Data` as its first 9 characters.

If you want to be more specific then we can create a string with all the name of the sheets concatenated.  Then see if the sheet name is in the string:

```
Sub delrow()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wsname As String
wsname = "CDGL Data,CDGL Data (2),CDGL Data (3),CDGL Data (4)"
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If InStr(wsname, ws.Name) Then
        Rows(1).Delete
    End If
Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Okay but how will I add multiple sheets?

Comment: This will do every sheet that starts with `CDGL Data`; so it will do `CDGL Data (2)` and the others.  Do you need more, Fewer,or all? @Hags

Comment: I tried both and neither work on the workbook, when I run them.

Comment: Put `msgbox "Here"` after the `For Each ...` line.  You should have to hit okay once for every sheet in your workbook.  We are trying to discover why it is doing nothing.

Comment: Actually try this in the samplace `MsgBox "'" & ws.Name & "'"` it will help show if there are spaces in the worksheet name that we do not see.  If there are gaps between the name and the `'` there are spaces where they do not belong.

Comment: `create a string with all the name of the sheets concatenated` brilliant